# Excel formula for if only criteria

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 Columns Nationality & Gender. Any formula which can sum up a particular Nationality and get me the count for Male or Female. Only Excel Formulas please.

| NATIONALITY | GENDER |
| --- | --- |
| INDIAN | MALE |
| AMERICAN | MALE |
| INDIAN | FEMALE |
| INDIAN | FEMALE |
| PAKISTANI | MALE |
| PAKISTANI | MALE |

Suppose if I want to know say "INDIAN"
How many Male and How many Female

Comment: Look into `COUNTIFS`

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using Pivot table option or You can use Countifs formula in Excel.

Example:
See in the attached image, I've pivoted the table. Dragged Nationality into row shelf and Gender in Column shelf. Also, dragged Gender in Values shelf to generate the desired outcome.

[image]
[image]

Please refer to the below image for achieving the same thing with a formula.
[image]

Comment: Thanks - but how can I use an Excel Countif formula with criteria

Comment: Just shared an update to my post. check it out and mark my answer as correct answer please.

Comment: Perfect! can you mark my answer as correct answer? To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.